# Why do I get an InvalidDocument exception when saving an object into MongoDB in Django for the first time?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I've been having a nightmare of a time trying to get MongoDB working with Django. I now have it successfully installed, but it errors upon the first attempt to save an object. I've been following [this tutorial](http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html), and the Post model they present I have copied precisely.

Here is the code for the model:

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField()
    comments = ListField()
```

The post is actually created (and inserted) here:

```
post = Post.objects.create(
...     title='Hello MongoDB!',
...     text='Just wanted to drop a note from Django. Cya!',
...     tags=['mongodb', 'django'],
...     comments=['comment 1', 'comment 2']
... )
```

The full stack trace [can be found here](http://dpaste.com/hold/732115/). The error itself is:

```
InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was <django.db.models.fields.CharField object at 0x22cae50>
```

Clearly MongoDB is functioning, because it wants the keys to be strings instead of integers. But why is the rum gone? Err, why are standard Django objects not able to save into the MongoDB database?

I have added the required CharField parameter max_length that was overlooked. It does not work in this case, nor does it if I also remove the lists.

Comment: Try adding the max_length arg to the Char and understand if the problem goes away when you remove the Lists.

Comment: @luke14free I removed the lists and added the max_length parameter, but it gives me the same error. It's worth noting that the error does not mention bad parameters.

Comment: You might want to consider django-nonrel as an alternative. It has a mongodb adapter.

Comment: @majdal I'm actually using django-nonrel.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error until updating the django-mongodb-engine library to the current version in the 'develop' branch of the github repository. Simply using the instructions on the article shown will import the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I have also followed this tutorial and had same error. I managed to fix this problem. 
What I did wrong is I used djangotoolbox from github (https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangotoolbox) repository, which was ver 0.9.2. Then I removed this and did it as tutorial states and used bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangotoolbox) that is on ver 0.9.1 of djangotoolbox. Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the late answer! If/when I choose to start a Django project with mongoDB again, I'll see if this is the solution and credit you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
post = Post(
...     title='Hello MongoDB!',
...     text='Just wanted to drop a note from Django. Cya!',
...     tags=['mongodb', 'django'],
...     comments=['comment 1', 'comment 2']
... )
```

Another thing to try:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200)
```

I think by default Django uses auto-generated numeric values as primary keys.  This would force your title to be your primary key... it's a char string, so it might solve the problem you're seeing.  It's just a guess, because the actual error your seeing doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: It does work, but I get the same errors when I then do post.save().

Comment: I'm not a MongoDB guy, but your code looks fine.  I suspect something is wrong with your system config.  You probably want to check the versions of MongoDB/django-nonrel you are using.  If you don't get help here, try the django-nonrel mailing list, there's a number of MongoDB folk there.

Comment: Thanks. I've been on their IRC channel with little luck, so perhaps I'll try the mailing list.

Comment: one other idea to try, probably won't fix your problem but might help you figure out what's wrong.  Check the answer above, I've added something else to try.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your model looks just fine. The error is funny; it is saying that the key to the attribute you are calling as "title" cannot be anything other than a string, but if I'm not mistaken, the string here is the key "title" and the value is the CharField() field, together representing a key/value pair in the Post document in your MongoDB. Try isolating the problem by jumping into the django shell:

```
python manage.py shell
```

and building your Post object from scratch. Use the model that dragonx has mentioned. Simple is best to debug these problems. If you are getting the same error when you try either to call Post.objects.create(p) for a Post object p, or when you call p.save(), try re-writing the Post model and give it another shot.

Finally, you can show us your settings.py file and see what your mongodb settings are there. If you say you are using django-nonrel, then there are basic checks you can make to ensure that python, django, and mongodb are talking to each other.

Let us know how you're doing.